# Grant Network Access PostgreSQL 9

Tags: postgresql, networking

I have a local network and want to allow remote access to the postgres server in the another computer.

The PostgreSQL suggests the following pg_hba.conf entry but it doesn't work:

```
host all all 192.168.0.0/24 md5
```

I get the following error:

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.137.1", user "postgres", database "postgres", 
SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.137.1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

It only works if I specify the IP address and mask like below:

```
host all all 192.168.137.1 255.255.255.0 md5
```

The server machine runs Ubuntu 10.11/Postgre 9 and client machine runs Windows 7 x64

Someone knows how can i allow all my network to access the server?

Comment: Older versions of PostgreSQL didn't understand the CIDR "x.x.x.x/n" format, they required long-format netmasks. If you specify the netmask the long way like you did in the second line it should work. If it doesn't, please make sure you restarted PostgreSQL after making the change and please specify your PostgreSQL version.

Comment: If your version of PostgreSQL supports CIDR addressing, wouldn't yours be `192.168.137.0/24`? 24 bits is the first three octets, isn't it?

Comment: I think this should be migrated to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bad netmask. If you want to add host 192.168.137.1 to 192.168.0.0 network, you have to use netmask even /16 or 255.255.0.0